# Got this error in compiling darknet in Colab: make: *** [darknet] Error 1

Tags: opencv, gcc, yolo, darknet

I have tried compiling [darknet](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet) last **May 11** in Colab (using [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fIK6g2oYyMrNheEmtVObWgU1JMrOv_e8?usp=sharing)) and it was alright.

Today, I tried to do the same code today (**June 1**) and I have this error below. I tried compiling in this [repo](https://github.com/roboflow-ai/darknet) and it turned out fine if LIBSO = 0.

June 1 settings:

```
CUDA Version: 11.2 
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 6
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5
Open CV 4.1.2
```

A snippet of the error message.

```
obj/parser.o: In function `parse_implicit':
parser.c:(.text+0x5831): undefined reference to `make_implicit_layer'
obj/parser.o: In function `save_implicit_weights':
parser.c:(.text+0x9a1c): undefined reference to `pull_implicit_layer'
obj/parser.o: In function `load_implicit_weights':
parser.c:(.text+0xb378): undefined reference to `push_implicit_layer'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:141: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

Full error message is [here](https://pastebin.com/204dvpRz)

Answer (score 0):

I just took out the 5th, 7th, and 8th cell in the [said notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1fIK6g2oYyMrNheEmtVObWgU1JMrOv_e8?usp=sharing) and Darknet was able to successfully compile.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this, the new Darknet/YOLO repo people should using is this one:  https://github.com/hank-ai/darknet#table-of-contents

Some example colabs showing how to install and run it can be found here:

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HMj8wswew5U2VRtzl--yfAU0WdUgWWZR
- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1EUR6Vv9R0upSnimD-hqcgo7DtrNzRvTS